# Can Unison ignore files by their size?

Tags: rsync, unison

The program rsync has the option `--max-size=SIZE` to prohibit transferring any file larger than `SIZE`. Does unison have a similar option?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `-copythreshold` option.  From the unison help flag:

```
-copythreshold n   use copyprog on files bigger than this (if >=0, in Kb)
```

You could make a dummy program/script that does nothing.  Usually I believe that you would specify rsync with special options as the copyprog, but if you don't want to copy anything, the copyprog should take no action.

Answer (score 2):

```
# ~/.unison/myprofile.prf

# Skip files larger than 200 megabytes

# Use copyprog with files larger than XXX Kb
copythreshold = 200000

# rsync will skip files that are too large
copyprog      =   rsync --inplace --compress ""--max-size=200M""
copyprogrest  =   rsync --partial --inplace --compress ""--max-size=200M""
```

Copied from the [Unison Wiki](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/?n=Main.UnisonFAQTips).

Answer (score 1):

[See also](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) `maxsizethreshold` parameter for precisely this. Either set in the prf project file or as a command line option, eg for 100Kb

```
unison project -maxsizethreshold 100
```

Comment: Does this option work? The documentation was for unison version 2.48.4